# Define a module and call its function in one file

Tags: module, ocaml

I have defined a module in a file `mod.ml` as follows:

```
module Area = struct
  ...
  let test : unit =
    Print.printf "haha"
  ...
end;;

Print.printf "hehe";;

Area.test
```

It seems that without `;;` after `end`, I can not compile the code by `ocamlc`. But it looks strange to me to have `;;` in a Ocaml file, do I have to keep them?

After generating `mod` by `ocamlc`, I launch `mod`, it prints `hahahehe`. It seems that `haha` is printed by the definition of `let test : unit ...` instead of its call `Area.test`. What I except as a result is `hehehaha` or `hahahehehaha`. Could anyone explain why it is not what I expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never use `;;` in my source files, I think of it as part of the top-level interface.  For your code I would probably write:

```
module Area = struct
  let test : unit -> unit =
      fun () -> Printf.printf "haha"
end

let () =
    Printf.printf "hehe";
    Area.test ()
```

For what it's worth, `Area.test` as you have defined it is not a function, it's just a unit value with a side effect during its computation.  In my code here I've changed it to a function of type `unit -> unit`.

Answer (score 4):

When `ocamlc` loads a module, it evaluates all the "toplevel" definitions, in the order in which they are defined. In your case, you have three "toplevel" definitions.

- The first one is the value `unit` (the only value of type `unit`), which is bind to the name "test". This value is generated after a side-effect: displaying "haha" (here the module `Area` serves as a namespace, it does not delay computation);
- The seconde one is the value `unit` as well, but without name binding; This value is also generated with a side-effect: displaying "hehe";
- The last one is simply the value associated to the name "test", ie. `unit`. However, this time, there is no side-effects as the value `unit` associated to the name "test" has already been generated.

If you want to have a side-effect each time you call test, you need to use a function:

```
let test () =  Print.printf "haha"
```

And for the `;;` part of your question. These are needed by the parser to know when an expression ends. There are other ways to help the parser, for instance:

```
let () = Print.printf "hehe"
```

Or simply:

```
let _ = Area.test
```

The latest is shorter because you don't have to indicate type information, but is more error-prone because the compiler will not warm you in case of partial application.